# MVC 3 DropDownFor and ViewModel not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010

I have a 2 Models:

```
public class Person
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set;}
}

public class Event
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string EventName { get; set; }
    public virtual Person Owner { get; set; }
}
```

I have a ViewModel:

```
public class EventViewModel
{
     public EventViewModel() { }
     public Event EventToEdit { get; set; }
     public SelectList People { get; set; }
}
```

I have my Controller:

```
public ViewResult Create()
{
     var eve = new Event();
     var vm = new EventViewModel
                 {
                     EventToEdit = eve,
                     People = GetPeopleList(true, eve)
                 }
     return View(vm)
 }
```

I have my View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.EventToEdit.Owner, Model.People)
```

Obviously they are cut down for reading purposes.

When I submit my view, and hit a breakpoint in the `ActionResult Create`

1. It doesn't have a value for Owner (the list is populated correctly)
2. The ViewModel People is also null

The point of using a ViewModel is carry information to and from the view to the controller so firstly why is People null.

Secondly and most importantly, why on earth is Owner not getting populated properly. There are people to choose from. Event name will be passed back through the model so the ViewModel is working somewhat...

Thanks,

Comment: via the ViewModel as shown above.

Comment: yes , sorry, i didn't see it :)

Comment: can you show us Create action? (with post verb)

Comment: have GetPeopleList(true, eve) populated the selectlist correctly?

Comment: The list is populated correctly as stated.

Comment: The Create action has the whole ViewModel posted back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking karaxuna's answer:

> First, it should be:
>
> `@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.EventToEdit.Owner.ID, Model.People)`
>
> So that Model.People was something like this:
>
> `new SelectList(source, "ID", "Name", source.ID)`

And expanding on that:

new ViewModel:

```
public class EventViewModel
{
    public EventViewModel() { }
    public Event EventToEdit { get; set; }
    public SelectList People { get; set; }
    public Guid SelectedPerson { get; set; }
}
```

View Binding:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedPerson, Model.People)
```

Then in the Controller:

```
var person = _repository.People.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID.CompareTo(vm.SelectedPerson) == 0);
vm.EventToEdit.Person = person;
_repository.SaveEvent(vm.EventToEdit);
```

I write this answer for clarity, anyone who comes searching might prefer to see a complete page.

Answer (score 4):

First, it should be:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.EventToEdit.Owner.ID, Model.People)
```

So that Model.People was something like this:

```
new SelectList(source, "ID", "Name", source.ID)
```

Comment: I saw something where doing what you described is wrong, however I am willing to give it a go and see what happens. (i saw it wrong in some posts, searching: dropdownlistfor mvc3)

Comment: So this is working, and posts the selected value back to Owner.ID, it just doesnt go through the database and populate it with the correct one. So I'm guessing that the correct way to do it is to see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Check the HTML to see what is placed in the value for the option elements in the HTML, I suspect that MVC cannot cast this value into `EventToEdit.Owner` as I think it can only handle strings and integers though you could write a custom modelbinder for this if you need to use another datatype.

ASP.Net will not post back the values used to populate the drop down list for efficiency ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541467/selectlist-returns-as-null-in-mvc-dropdownlist)).

Personally I find the drop down lists not very helpful, they're designed to show data directly from the database, so you'd be able to re-query to get the SelectList values in the controller as needed and link them back to this re-queried list by placing simple IDs in the option values.

Comment: So are you saying, get the stored selectedvalue from the list, then query the database and then populate the Person in the controller. That makes sense.

Comment: The above is one approach - having fields in your ViewModel for the IDs for your `People` and `Event` objects (like `List<PeopleID>` and `EventID`) and then 'rehydrating' these objects in your post controller. Another option would be to flatten the objects out using Automapper, then map the values back in your post controller (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580392/how-to-map-multiple-objects-to-one-object-using-automapper-asp-net-mvc-3).

Comment: Also see this tutorial http://consultingblogs.emc.com/owainwragg/archive/2010/12/22/automapper-mapping-from-multiple-objects.aspx